# ExtJS Drag & Drop gives "TypeError: path is undefined" on drop

Tags: extjs

I'm using ExtJS 6.0.1 and want to drag items from a grid over a tree so I can change some category values into the grid records.

But on drop event I get this error: "`TypeError: path is undefined`". The error is returned by the function ensureVisible from `Ext.tree Panel` class, first line.

```
        var foldersStore = Ext.create("Ext.data.TreeStore",{
                storeId: 'foldersTreeStore',
                proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',
                    url: 'categories/tree.json'
                },
                autoLoad: true
            });

            var foldersTree = Ext.create("Ext.tree.Panel",{
                title: 'Categories',
                hideHeaders: true,
                renderTo: 'folders-tree',
                rootVisible: false,
                allowDeselect: true,
                store: foldersStore,
                droppedRecords: undefined,
                viewConfig: {
                    plugins: {
                        ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop',
                        dragText: 'Drag and drop to reorganize',
                        dropGroup: 'bkmDDGroup',
                        appendOnly: true
                    },
                    listeners: {
                        beforedrop: function(node, data, overModel, dropPos, opts) {
                            this.droppedRecords = data.records;
                            data.records = [];

                            console.log(this.droppedRecords);
                        },
                        drop: function(node, data, overModel, dropPos, opts) {
                            console.log(arguments);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            var filesStore = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store",{
                storeId:'filesTableStore',
                fields:[
                    {name: 'eid', type:'string'},
                    {name: 'fileName', type:'string'},
                    {name: 'createdAt', type:'string'},
                    {name: 'mimeType', type:'string'},
                    {name: 'version', type:'string'},
                    {name: 'size', type:'int'},
                    {name: 'creator', type:'string'},
                    {name: 'modifier', type:'string'},
                    {name: 'status', type:'string'},
                    {name: 'tmpId'}
                ],
                proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',
                    url: 'documents/list.json',
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        rootProperty: "list"
                    }
                },
                autoLoad: true
            });

            var filesTable = Ext.create("Ext.grid.Panel",{
                store: filesStore,
                title:'Files',
                selModel: {
                    mode: "MULTI",
                    allowDeselect: true
                },
                columns:[
                    {
                    text:'File Name',
                    flex:1,
                    dataIndex:'fileName'
                },{
                    text:'Created By',
                    flex:1,
                    dataIndex:'creator'
                },{
                    text:'Mime Type',
                    width: 150,
                    dataIndex:'mimeType'
                },{
                    text:'Size',
                    width: 100,
                    dataIndex:'size'
                },{
                    text:'Version',
                    width: 80,
                    dataIndex: 'version'
                },{
                    text:'Status',
                    width: 100,
                    dataIndex:'status'
                },{
                    text:'Created At',
                    width:150,
                    dataIndex:'createdAt'
                }],
                renderTo:'files-table',
                height:UI.getContentHeight("#files-table"),
                viewConfig: {
                    plugins: {
                        ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
                        dragText: 'Drag and drop to reorganize',
                        dragGroup: 'bkmDDGroup'
                    }
                }
            });
```

From my point of view looks like I've forgot some config, still don't have any idea yet. Even if I have a single console.log line in drop event, the error remains the same.

Any clues will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Provide please the fiddle with a problem https://fiddle.sencha.com

Comment: Here is my fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1v30&view/editor

Answer (score 0):

In the beforedrop listener you are deleting the records you've selected:

```
data.records = []
```

Instead you must prepare that records to drop into TreePanel where data model differs from the grid.

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/mgill21/3HJXX/2/) to the realization

Comment: I'm afraid your example doesn't work in ExtJS 6. The example is using version 4. Yes, I'm deleting the records, otherwise they will be removed from the grid. I want also to remove them from that list but only after a success ajax call which should change in the DB the category (tree element) of those files (grid elements). I've removed everything from the beforedrop and drop events and the error persists. I remember, I'm using version 6.0.1.

Comment: Try [copy](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.grid.plugin.DragDrop.html) property. And after that you can delete record from the source grid when you want.

Comment: delete `data.records = []` and add `copy: true` property to `gridviewdragdrop` plugin